# Cannot remove parameter content type from wso2 apim API console

Tags: soap, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I want to use API console in wso2 apim 1.8.0 to test my soap service, but there is a field named parameter content type displayed there with application/json as value (no other options to select in drop down list box).

I tried editing swagger (version 1.2) but could not able to disable the parameter content type field from api console nor add application/xml option there.

It would be better if someone suggest a method to remove the field from api console.

NOTE: the parameter content type is not a user defined parameter for the method, it appears by default in API CONSOLE (try it out console)

Thanks in advance,
Naresh

Comment: Do you mean Response Content Type  property?

Comment: No not content type property. A field name property content type with drop down list box is displayed in API Console which has only json as content type value. Though i explicitly add Content-Type property and provide value as xml the value taken as JSON only.

Comment: Refer This Link [WSO2 API Manager Document - Adding Content-Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870973/cannot-remove-parameter-content-type-from-wso2-apim-api-console)

Answer (score 0):

To add,change content-types shown in API Console, the Swagger Definition of the API needs to be edited. 
Therefore as an example you have to define ["text/xml","text/plain"] at the API level, if you need multiple options for Content Type